# substring() method for linked list object

Tags: java, linked-list, substring

I'm having some trouble writing a `substring()` method for a class I'm building called `LString`. This class creates a linked list object called `LString` that builds strings. It mimics the `String` and `StringBuilder` objects in Java.

`substring(int start, int end)` creates a new `LString` out of the given `this` LString, from the index provided by `start` to `end`. It returns type `LString`.

Here is the error message without any edits to make `end` inclusive:

```
Running substring tests (63 tests)
Starting tests: ......E........................................................
Time: 0.031

There was 1 failure:
1) test43cSubStringOneChar(LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial)
java.lang.AssertionError: Substring of One Character LString is not equals LString expected: LString<a> but was: LString<a>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial.test43cSubStringOneChar(LStringTest.java:401)
        ... 10 more

Test Failed! (1 of 63 tests failed.)

Test failures: abandoning other phases.
```

This produces a simpler error message, with only 1 failure.

Here is the code corresponding to that error message:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LString    {

     node   front;
     int size;

     //Creating a node class
     private    class   node {
          char data;
          node next;

          public    node (){
          }

          public    node    (char   newData){
                this.data = newData;
          }

          public    node    (char   newData,    node newNext){
                this.data = newData;
                this.next = newNext;
          }


     }
     //Constructors
     public LString(){
          this.size =   0;
          this.front =  null;
     }
     public LString(String original)    {
          this.size = original.length();
          if (original.length() > 0){

              this.front =  new node(original.charAt(0));
              node curr = this.front;

              for   (int i =1; i <  original.length(); i++) {
                    curr.next = new node(original.charAt(i));
                    curr = curr.next;
              }
          }



     }

    //  Length method,  returns the length of LString
     public int length()    {
        return this.size;
    }

    //  compareTo method,   compares    this LString to anotherLString, returns 0   if  equal,
    //  -1  if  lexicogrpahically   less,   and 1   if  lexicographically   greater
    public int compareTo(LString anotherLString)    {
        int len1    = length();
        int len2    = anotherLString.length();
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);

        node cn1    = front;
        node cn2    = anotherLString.front;

        int k   = 0;
        while   (k  < lim) {
            char c1 = cn1.data;
            char c2 = cn2.data;
            if  (c1 != c2) {
                return c1-c2;
            }
            k++;
            cn1 =   cn1.next;
            cn2 =   cn2.next;
        }
        return len1 - len2;

    }

    //  a boolean equals method that returns true   if  LString and other   are the same, false if not
    public boolean  equals(Object other)    {
        if  (this   ==  other) {
            return true;
        }
        if  (other instanceof   LString)    {
            LString otherLString    = (LString)other;
            int n   = length();
            if  (n  ==  otherLString.length()) {
                node n1 = front;
                node n2 = otherLString.front;
                while   (n1 != null) {
                    if  (n1.data    !=  n2.data)    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    n1  = n1.next;
                    n2  = n2.next;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    //  charAt returns  the character of LString at the argument index
    public char charAt(int index)   {

        if  ((index < 0) || (index >= this.length()))   {
            throw   new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        node curNode =  front;
        for (int    i = 0; i    < this.length(); i++, curNode   = curNode.next) {
            if  (i  ==  index) {
                return curNode.data;
            }
        }
        throw   new IllegalStateException();
    }

    //
    public void setCharAt(int index,    char ch)    {
      if (index < 0 || index >= this.length()) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      else {
         node currNode = front;
         for (int i = 0; i <this.length(); i++, currNode = currNode.next) {
            if (i == index) {
            currNode.data = ch;
            }
         }
      }
   }

    public LString  substring(int start,    int end)    {
      if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || start > end) {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      LString substring = new LString();
      if (start == end) {
         return substring;
      }
      node node = this.front;
      for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
         node = node.next;
      }
      node copy = new node(node.data);
      substring.front = copy;
      for (int i = start+1; i < end; i++) {
         node = node.next;
         copy = copy.next = new node(node.data);
      }
      return substring;      
    }
    public LString  replace(int start, int end, LString lStr)   {
        return null;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result    = new   StringBuilder();

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr   !=  null){

            result.append(curr.data);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

A few notes: I did write a `toString()` method, and in this code is also a `replace()` method, which I'll write after this.

Here is the error and code for making `end` inclusive:

Error:

```
Running substring tests (63 tests)
Starting tests: E....EEE....E.EEEEEE.....E.EEEEEEE....E.EEEEEEE....E.EEEEEEE...
Time: 0.028

There were 35 failures:
1) test41aSubStringEmpty(LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial.test41aSubStringEmpty(LStringTest.java:368)
        ... 10 more
2) test43bSubStringOneChar(LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial.test43bSubStringOneChar(LStringTest.java:395)
        ... 10 more
3) test43cSubStringOneChar(LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial.test43cSubStringOneChar(LStringTest.java:401)
        ... 10 more
4) test43dSubStringOneCharIsNew(LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial.test43dSubStringOneCharIsNew(LStringTest.java:407)
        ... 10 more
5) test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:468)
        ... 10 more
6) test51dSubstringAtStart[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not correct expected:<a[]> but was:<a[b]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51dSubstringAtStart(LStringTest.java:478)
        ... 10 more
7) test51eSubstringAtEnd[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51eSubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:483)
        ... 10 more
8) test51fSubstringInMiddle[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not correct expected:<[]> but was:<[b]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51fSubstringInMiddle(LStringTest.java:488)
        ... 10 more
9) test51gSubstringAll[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51gSubstringAll(LStringTest.java:493)
        ... 10 more
10) test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not new LString expected:<a[]> but was:<a[b]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew(LStringTest.java:500)
        ... 10 more
11) test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew[0](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew(LStringTest.java:505)
        ... 10 more
12) test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:468)
        ... 10 more
13) test51dSubstringAtStart[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not correct expected:<a[]> but was:<a[b]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51dSubstringAtStart(LStringTest.java:478)
        ... 10 more
14) test51eSubstringAtEnd[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51eSubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:483)
        ... 10 more
15) test51fSubstringInMiddle[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not correct expected:<b[]> but was:<b[c]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51fSubstringInMiddle(LStringTest.java:488)
        ... 10 more
16) test51gSubstringAll[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51gSubstringAll(LStringTest.java:493)
        ... 10 more
17) test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not new LString expected:<a[]> but was:<a[b]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew(LStringTest.java:500)
        ... 10 more
18) test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew(LStringTest.java:505)
        ... 10 more
19) test51kSubstringInMiddleIsNew[1](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not new LString expected:<b[]> but was:<b[c]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51kSubstringInMiddleIsNew(LStringTest.java:515)
        ... 10 more
20) test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:468)
        ... 10 more
21) test51dSubstringAtStart[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not correct expected:<A long []> but was:<A long [s]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51dSubstringAtStart(LStringTest.java:478)
        ... 10 more
22) test51eSubstringAtEnd[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51eSubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:483)
        ... 10 more
23) test51fSubstringInMiddle[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not correct expected:<ng str[]> but was:<ng str[i]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51fSubstringInMiddle(LStringTest.java:488)
        ... 10 more
24) test51gSubstringAll[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51gSubstringAll(LStringTest.java:493)
        ... 10 more
25) test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not new LString expected:<A long []> but was:<A long [s]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew(LStringTest.java:500)
        ... 10 more
26) test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew(LStringTest.java:505)
        ... 10 more
27) test51kSubstringInMiddleIsNew[2](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not new LString expected:<ng str[]> but was:<ng str[i]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51kSubstringInMiddleIsNew(LStringTest.java:515)
        ... 10 more
28) test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51bEmptySubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:468)
        ... 10 more
29) test51dSubstringAtStart[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not correct expected:<This is an even[]> but was:<This is an even[ ]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51dSubstringAtStart(LStringTest.java:478)
        ... 10 more
30) test51eSubstringAtEnd[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51eSubstringAtEnd(LStringTest.java:483)
        ... 10 more
31) test51fSubstringInMiddle[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not correct expected:<an even longer[]> but was:<an even longer[ ]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51fSubstringInMiddle(LStringTest.java:488)
        ... 10 more
32) test51gSubstringAll[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51gSubstringAll(LStringTest.java:493)
        ... 10 more
33) test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(0, mid) is not new LString expected:<This is an even[]> but was:<This is an even[ ]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51hSubstringAtStartIsNew(LStringTest.java:500)
        ... 10 more
34) test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at LString.substring(LString.java:142)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51jSubstringAtEndIsNew(LStringTest.java:505)
        ... 10 more
35) test51kSubstringInMiddleIsNew[3](LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: substring(left, right) is not new LString expected:<an even longer[]> but was:<an even longer[ ]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSubStringTest.test51kSubstringInMiddleIsNew(LStringTest.java:515)
        ... 10 more

Test Failed! (35 of 63 tests failed.)

Test failures: abandoning other phases.
```

Here is the relevant differences in code, only `substring()` is different:

```
public LString  substring(int start,    int end)    {
  if (start < 0 || end >= this.length() || start > end) {
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
  }
  LString substring = new LString();
  /*if (start == end) {
     return substring;
  }*/
  node node = this.front;
  for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
     node = node.next;
  }
  node copy = new node(node.data);
  substring.front = copy;
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
     node = node.next;
     copy = copy.next = new node(node.data);
  }
  return substring;      
}
```

Section from `LStringTest` regarding the error:

```
   @Test public void test43aSubStringOneChar() {
         LString testLString = new LString("a");
         assertEquals("Substring of One Character LString is not Empty",
               nullLString, testLString.substring(0, 0));
      }

      @Test public void test43bSubStringOneChar() {
         LString testLString = new LString("a");
         assertEquals("Substring of One Character LString is not Empty",
               nullLString, testLString.substring(1, 1));
      }

      @Test public void test43cSubStringOneChar() {
         LString testLString = new LString("a");
         assertEquals("Substring of One Character LString is not equals LString",
               testLString, testLString.substring(0, 1));
      }
```

Comment: The tests are definitely expecting exclusive end. I need to see the code for the method *LStringTest$LStringSubStringTestSpecial.test43cSubStringOneChar()*. Please include that code in your question.

Comment: I added the code for all SubStringOneChar() methods

Comment: The bug is in your equals method. See if you can figure out why equals is returning the wrong answer for string length 1.

Comment: Alright I think I know the problem. Add the line `substring.size = end - start;` just before the `return` statement at the end of the substring method. I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: ah yes! I forgot about changing size. Thanks for your help. I'll move on to the replace method now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in that other answer doesn't compile, and even if it did, doesn't function correctly.

Assuming you're using standard (for Java) zero-based indexing, and that the `end` index is exclusive, this code compiles and is tested.

```
public LString substring(int start, int end) {
    if (start < 0 || end > length() || start > end) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    LString result = new LString();
    if (start == end) {
        return result;
    }
    node node = this.front;
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
        node = node.next;
    }
    node copy = new node(node.data);
    result.front = copy;
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
        node = node.next;
        copy = copy.next = new node(node.data);
    }
    result.size = end - start;
    return result;
}
```

If you wanted `end` to be inclusive, though this would be against Java convention, you would change three things:

1. the guard clause at the start of the method would have to say `end >= length()` instead of `end > length()`,
2. the second guard clause `if (start == end) { return substring; }` would need to be removed entirely, and
3. the last for loop would initialize `int i = start` instead of `int i = start + 1`.

By the way, it's much easier to see what's happening with your `LString` instances if you have a `toString()` method in the class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (this.front == null) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length());
    node node = this.front;
    do sb.append(node.data);
    while ((node = node.next) != null);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what would I do if end was inclusive?

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding `end` inclusive - it's not conventional for Java. And you could never get an empty substring because, for instance, `substring(3, 3)` would return the fourth character but `substring(3, 2)` would be invalid. But to make it work inclusive, you would have to change two things: 1) the guard clause at the start of the method would have to say `end >= length()` instead of `end > length()`, and 2) the last `for` loop would initialize `int i = start` instead of `int i = start + 1`.

Comment: Correction, you would have to change three things for end inclusive: 3) remove the second guard clause `if (start == end) { return substring; }`. See also my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. If you don't mind continuing, you're helping me a lot. I made the edits, including the third one, but am receiving more errors than my original error. It seems to be adding more than it needs to.

Comment: Make an edit to your question, include your new code in a separate section, and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: You are right, I did not compile it! but you have to admit that _your_ solution is just the same as mine... debuged. well done!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't review all the code but just put the logic for the `substring()` method. Since you can mutate an `LString` by setting some char at a given position, I took the hypothesis that you really want a copy of the linked-list for the substring: you don't want a behaviour where you take a substring, modify the parent string and have the substring modified.

You can implement a "clever" implementation that won't actually copy the nodes until it is necessary. For instance, you can have the substring *observe* the parent string for any modification that would impact the nodes of the substring. And when there is one, the copy will occur. See the [Observer/Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) pattern to implement this. In your case, if you keep only one class, `LString` it will implement both `Observer` and `Observable`.

Anyway, here is the simple copy implementation

```
public LString  substring(int start,    int end)    {
    if (start < 0 || end > this.length() || start > end) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (start == end) {
        return new LString(); // return an "empty" LString
    }

    // Find starting node
    Node currentNode = front;
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    // create new LString and copy each node from start to end
    LString ls = new LString();
    ls.front = new node(currentNode.data)
    node newCur = ls.front;
    for (int i = start+1; i<end; i++) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        node newNext = new node(currentNode.data);
        newCur.next = newNext;
        newCur = newNext;
    }
    ls.size = end-start;
    return ls;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of help. For now I'm going to stick with just copying it into a new LString. I have other methods I need to write. Quick question, with this implementation I receive an error for an LString substring of one character, in this case 'a', where the error message is "AssertionError" , any ideas why that is? I can't see anything at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I actually wrote this without compiling and there was a few details to correct (like the `size` and the declaration of `int` in the `for`)... Well, the other solution has obviously debugged mine ;)